# Change 'dest' option dynamically

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-sass

**Hi all,**

Following this question : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/190

I'm trying to specify the *'dest'* option depending on the *'src*' one.
The only difference is the */scss* that has to be removed.

Here is a sample of my current code :

```
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          sourcemap: 'none',
          trace: true,
        },
        files: {
          './css/laptop.css': './scss/css/laptop.scss',
         ....
         ... (160 more lines)
         ....
          './css/player.css': './scss/css/player.scss'
        }
      }
    },
```

I tried

```
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      src: ['**/*.scss'],
      dest: function(path) { return path.replace(/(\/scss)/,"") },
      ext: '.css'
    }]
```

But apparently `Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.`

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I discovered grunt-newer which can be used this way:

```
  css:{
    files: [
      './scss/**'
    ],
    tasks: ['newer:sass'],
    livereload: {
      options: { livereload: true },
      files: ['./**'],
    },
  }
```

It's not what I was trying to do exactly but It optimised perfectly the grunt process. Really nice plugin!!